# For "social justice", can I write (..........is just socially or ......is fair socially)

Tags: word-choice

> Despite the fact that some people believe that imposing wage ceiling might be more **just / fair** socially, I believe that removing any restrictions on people's income is good for the economy.

Is it correct phrase in formal writing "just socially", I am trying to talk about "social justice" term.  I prefer "...just socially" because it is little bit uncommon and the examiner of IELTS might give more more marks for it,
but I need to know whether it is correct.

Comment: As far as I can tell, neither is idiomatic. It should be either *socially just* or *socially fair*. And which you use depends on what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Socially" relates to "just / fair" and therefore has to be placed before. Same as:

> **<strike>shirt white</strike>** vs. **white shirt**

Therefore your sentence should be:

> Despite the fact that some people believe that imposing wage ceiling might be more **socially just / fair**, I believe that removing any restrictions on people's income is good for the economy.

Both "just" and "fair" can be used, with their respective meanings (i.e. they do not mean exactly the same thing).